# Material Design Web 1.0: How to center the (--full-bleed) button text within a card?

Tags: html, css, button, material-design

I am experimenting with Material Design Web 1.0 from March 2019.

When using a [card](https://material.io/develop/web/components/cards/) and a [button](https://material.io/develop/web/components/buttons/) with in it, while the button has been set to be `mdc-card__actions--full-bleed` I found no way to center the button text. So my question is:

How to correctly center the button text in this example?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; script-src 'unsafe-inline' https://unpkg.com; style-src 'unsafe-inline' https://unpkg.com https://fonts.googleapis.com"/>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>

    <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"/>
    <style>
      .my-card-content 
       {
        padding: 16px;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mdc-card my-card-content">
      <div class="mdc-card__actions mdc-card__actions--full-bleed">
        <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised mdc-card__action mdc-card__action--button" tabindex="0">
          <span class="mdc-button__label">Login</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want to use full-width button?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
.mdc-button {
    justify-content: center !important;
}
```

```css
.my-card-content {
 padding: 16px;
}
.mdc-button {
 justify-content: center !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; script-src 'unsafe-inline' https://unpkg.com; style-src 'unsafe-inline' https://unpkg.com https://fonts.googleapis.com"/>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TMS Archiv login</title>

    <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"/>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="mdc-card my-card-content">
  <div class="mdc-card__actions mdc-card__actions--full-bleed">
    <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised mdc-card__action mdc-card__action--button" tabindex="0">
      <span class="mdc-button__label">Login</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok works, but only with the !important - which looks strange to me, because I would not expect this from a google framework. Last but not least I used .my-mdc-button as style to not  interfere with the material classes.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of .mdc-card__action--button class has `justify-content: space-between;` property and value therefore if you want to center that text you should override this property with following code:

```
.mdc-card__action--button {
  justify-content: center !important;
}
```